# How to show that the trace maps a Galois extension to the base field

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be a finite extension of the finite field $F$, then the *trace* is defined as
$$\operatorname{Tr}(\alpha) = \sum_{\sigma \,\in\, \operatorname{Gal}(K/F)}\sigma(\alpha)$$
How can one show that $\operatorname{Tr}(\alpha) \in F, \forall \alpha \in K$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that for any $\;\tau\in \text{ Gal}\,(K/F)\;$ we get

$$\tau(Tr(\alpha))=\sum_{\sigma\in Gal(K/F)}\tau\sigma\alpha=Tr(\alpha)$$

since as $\;\sigma\;$ runs over all the elements of the Galois group so does $\;\tau\sigma\;$ , and this means the trace is in the fixed field of the whole group, which means $\;Tr(\alpha)\in F$

Answer (score 2):

But in his original question, Anfänger did not assume that the extension K/F is Galois, although he states that his morphisms *s* run through a certain Gal(K/F). Perhaps it's just a matter of notations, but I think that the correct definition should be: K/F is *separable*, and Tr(a) is defined as the sum of the *s*(a) when *s* runs through the [K : F] embeddings of K into an algebraic closure which fix F pointwise. If K = F(a), an easy computation shows that - Tr(a) is the second coefficient of the monic irreducible polynomial for a over F, so Tr(a) belongs to F. In the general case, with F < F(a) < K, the "transition formula" for the trace maps does the job.

NB : if K/F admits a non trivial inseparable part, the trace is identically null.

Comment: I apologize, I was asking about Galois extensions specifically but did not know what they were when I asked this question.  I have updated the title to be more precise.